# inheritance in boo

Tags: inheritance, boo

if boo language is 100% compatible with c#,how can i have inheritance in 2 boo file like two c# class?

Comment: I don't know Boo, but I doubt a file is the equivalent to a class and therefore there's no such thing as inheritance between files...

Comment: As delnan commented, I don't understand how you related files and classes and inheritance. Can you elaborate, or post examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boo is a CLR language just like C#.  Assuming that references are properly resolved, inheritance is as simple as:

```
class A(B): // class A inherits from B
```

For more information, see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/BOO/Part+08+-+Classes